# How to display a image that has been uploaded to spree(RoR) banners?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-activestorage

First, I've created a model with scaffold, "Banners", where I'll upload/store 3 images with specific names, like "main-banner-1", "main-banner-2", "main-banner-3".

My `app/models/banner.rb`

```
class Banner < ApplicationRecord
has_one_attached :image   end
```

In the `app/views/spree/admin/banners/show.html.erb` I can normally display the image using

```
<%= image_tag(main_app.url_for(@banner.image)) %>
```

My goal is to display this image in the spree home-page/main-page

On the `app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb` file we have

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= image_url('homepage/main_banner.png') %>" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= image_url('homepage/main_banner.png') %>" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= image_url('homepage/main_banner.png') %>" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**What I'm looking for** is the possibility to render the images in that page, below:

Instead of

`<img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= image_url('homepage/main_banner.png') %>" alt="Third slide">`

you can go with something like

`<img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= image_tag(main_app.url_for(@banner.image)) %>" alt="Third slide">`

How can I bring the `@banner` I want, to the `<img>`, to display the image on the spree banners.